# Can't get Bcrypt.checkpw to verify password in java play framework

Tags: java, bcrypt, playframework-2.3

I have had an application written a few years ago and upgraded some of the jars but not the bcrypt

It is written in java using the play framework.

BCrypt is provided from "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"

I use BCrypt.checkpw(password.trim(), user.getPassword())

where password is the captured plaintext and user.getPassword is the stored hash in mysql stored as char(60).

I hash passwords using BCrypt.hashpw(password.trim(), BCrypt.gensalt(15))

checkpw works interestingly with original passwords but any new ones it fails and always responds false

One interesting observation is I had a password in my dev database which I know is 'password' 
Its hash looks like this

$2a$10$UvKgjjT./SuMlD6gsoyD0e2lBcOwFtL/mfGmneTou/lrU1R/ZwMLK

vs

a new one I just created and set its password to 'password'

and its hash looks like this

$2a$10$rNJzD52/muHMkBF1Co9XF.VkQNRHQ3HCW.DYzke7jnY424voZwyq6

I know they should differ but the format looks different somewhat?

Please any help appreciated as this makes no sense as nothing has changed but new users cannot register

Code:
The password is set within my User class

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
        play.Logger.debug("setPassword |" + password.trim() +"|");
        this.password = BCrypt.hashpw(password.trim(), BCrypt.gensalt(15));
}
```

I call this within my register method

```
public Result registeruser() {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
.
.
.
        if (json.has("password")) {
          user.setPassword(json.findPath("password").textValue())
        }
.
.
.
       user.save()
.
.
.
}
```

I then have the following Authenticate method

```
public static Users authenticate(String email, String password) {
        play.Logger.debug("email is " + email);
        play.Logger.debug("authenticate password entered |" + password.trim() +"|");

        Users user = Users.find.query().where().eq("email", email).findOne();
        if (user != null) {
            play.Logger.debug("password hash from db |" + user.getPassword() +"|");
            Boolean checkPassword = BCrypt.checkpw(password.trim(), user.getPassword());
            play.Logger.debug("checkPassword " + checkPassword);
            if (checkPassword) {               
                    return user;
            } else {
                    return null;
            }
       }
}
```

Relevant debug output from running

```
In setPassword part
[debug] application - setPassword |password|

in authenticate part
[debug] application - authenticate password entered |password|
[debug] application - password hash from db |$2a$10$EiuMUWfbCoO.A1GxKk9YeOhqtK0bn4O8Y/W9U/7bEN/CSObOm6jUa|
[debug] application - checkPassword false
```

Comment: The second hashed password string should be `$2a$10$rNJzD52/muHMkBF1Co9XF.q.0AsvpnZuNauOq68wZIZ80df/ZV5ee`, as it is the valid hash string for the input `"password"`. Your second hashed password string is from a different password input.

Comment: Both are password. I can login with the 1st & I created the 2nd with debug
[debug] application - password $2a$10$rCYAaZateKa/NPm9.TKnGu2R0MUqQKjSNsJ5H79GHgx0.vzXEl1l.
[debug] application - checkPassword false. Code: play.Logger.debug("password " + password);
        Users user = Users.find.query().where().eq("email", email).findOne();
        if (user != null) {
            play.Logger.debug("password " + user.getPassword());
            Boolean checkPassword = BCrypt.checkpw(password.trim(), user.getPassword());
            play.Logger.debug("checkPassword " + checkPassword);

Comment: Not sure where you get the hash values from, but the hash value for the input `password` and the given salt should be `$2a$10$rCYAaZateKa/NPm9.TKnGuD1UIczZXiv1fgEXRX/XvKcFjZgOEVq6`, not the one you wrote in the comment. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Do not add source codes to your comments, add them to your question instead.

Comment: I added code in question and I actually changed the db to char(60) now from varchar but I have a few thousand passwords in the db all are/were 60 characters

Comment: Please change the logging message in the setter of the `password` field to `"setPassword called with: "+password` and then run your application again. Then [edit] your question to include the complete logging messages you get from new user registration and the complete logging messages you get from the authenticate call.

Comment: Please also add an additional logging entry in the setter of the password field which outputs the generated hash value before it is saved into the database. Update the logging output for both calls since the hash will be different. It's a long shot, but also add the result of `password.length()` to the first logging message in the setter, maybe the input contains some weird characters we can't see (however I doubt it this is the case...).

Comment: Does anyone know why when I add String pwd = json.findPath("password").textValue();
                String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(pwd, BCrypt.gensalt(15)); and log hashed its blank (ie before I call the setPassword) but in the database the hash exists?

Comment: The return value of `BCrypt.hashpw()` cannot be empty or blank, so the problem that you log a blank value is somewhere else (and difficult to say without the source code or a MCVE).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was in setPassword was not the right place to do the hashing and I kept getting a blank hashpw. This used to work in the earlier version of play but clearly not anymore

I moved it to a @PrePersist method as follows:

```
@PrePersist
    public void hashPassword(){
        play.Logger.debug("hashPassword |" + this.password +"|");
        String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(this.password, BCrypt.gensalt(15));
        play.Logger.debug("hashed " + hashed);
        this.password = hashed;
    }
```

Problem was solved